# ユーザーデータをメタデータサーバ経由で更新する方法

Tags: soracom

以下のリクエストでAir SIMからユーザーデータを取得できることはわかったのですが、ユーザーデータを更新するためのURLおよびリクエストの仕様(リクエストボディ、Content-Type)を教えてください。

```
curl -s http://metadata.soracom.io/v1/userdata
```

https://blog.soracom.jp/blog/2015/11/27/air-metadata/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ユーザーデータはグループ全体で共有されている情報ですので、いずれか 1 つの SIM から容易に変更できてしまうのは問題が起こりやすいのではないかと考えておりまして、現時点ではユーザーデータの更新には従来の認証が必要な API を用いていただくことを想定しております。

/v1/groups/{group_id}/configuration/{namespace} API に対して以下のようなフォーマットでデータを PUT していただくことでユーザーデータを更新できます。

[ { "key": "userdata", "value": "(任意の文字列)" } ]

API の Path の group_id にはユーザーデータを設定したいグループの group_id を、namespace には "SoracomAir" をそれぞれ指定してください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました！設計について理解できました。APIを叩くようにします。